# MS Word: Add hidden comments

Tags: python, ms-word

I am working on a word document and I generate a lot of tables and figures from Python code. For my reference, I want to create links to the github repo or parameters used in the code. This is for my view only. But, I also want to share this document with others without revealing these "notes". Is there a way to do this in word?

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't store information that people cannot find is they know how.  Ways to store information is via Docvariables and Custom properties. Is Readonly documents an option?

Comment: But if you use vba then you can store the information in a module and password protect it